# Keep space while storing lines into array

Tags: arrays, bash, space, lines

I did not find the solution on the site.

How can I store text contents into array in bash?

This code actually do it but space before strings are removed.

```
index=0

while read line; do
echo $line
str_array[index]="$line"
done < /testfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
index=0

while IFS= read line ; do
    str_array[$index]="$line" 
    index=$(($index+1))
done < testfile
```

**or** *as @glennjackman suggested in the comments*

```
index=0

while IFS= read line ; do
    str_array[index++]="$line" 
done < testfile
```

Comment: If you want to tighten it up a bit: `str_array[index++]="$line"` or `str_array+=("$line")`

Answer (score 2):

for bash, use the builtin `mapfile`:

```
$ cat testfile
asdf
 asdf
  asdf
   asdf
$ mapfile -t str_array < testfile
$ printf "%s\n" "${str_array[@]}"
asdf
 asdf
  asdf
   asdf
```

at a bash prompt, see `help mapfile`

Answer (score 1):

You need to undefine field separator, so it would be like:

```
while IFS= read line; do
  echo "$line"
  ...
done < /testfile
```

Comment: I also propose to `echo "$line"` instead of just `echo $line`.